# How to expose private git repo during docker build without including ssh key in image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to use the ADD command to expose a private git LFS repo during the docker build process but I keep getting errors:

```
------
> git://192.168.189.143/REPO/my-libs.git:
#37 0.761 Permission denied, please try again.
#37 0.819 Permission denied, please try again.
#37 0.883 git@192.168.189.143: Permission denied (publickey,password).
#37 0.885 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#37 0.885 
#37 0.885 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#37 0.885 and the repository exists.
------
failed to load cache key: failed to fetch remote git@192.168.189.143:REPO/my-libs.git: exit status 128
```

Here's the reference to the command:

[image]

My docker file looks like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile-upstream:master-labs
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV USER=markf78
USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /home/${USER}/temp
ADD git@192.168.189.143:REPO/my-libs.git /home/${USER}/temp
```

My build command on my MacOS X host is

```
docker build -t my-image --ssh default .
```

I am able to successfully clone from the terminal on the MacOS X host using my ed25519 SSH key.

Any ideas how to fix this? I realize there are other solutions available but this one seems the cleanest as it does not store my private key in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Do not clone the repo inside the image build, you do not need to do that at all.

Just put the Dockerfile in the / of the repo (also commit it to the repo to have it version controlled), and COPY the repo files with a Dockerfile command inside the image: `COPY . .`
First dot is the source that is your current directory on your machine that is your git repo, second dot is the target, the working dir inside the image. You build the image and publish it, push it to a docker registry so others can pull it and start using it. If you want more complex stuff building and publishing with a help of a server, look up CI/CD techniques.

Comment: I need binary files from a git LFS repo that we want included in the image.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you store in your git repo or any file host solution for building a docker image. I have never worked with Git LFS but you will need to checkout the files that are stored on remote to your local drive and do as I wrote. It doesn't matter if you pull the files from git with git pull or copy with ftp etc before issuing the docker build command. Also your local machine is the build machine, later you will want to put this workload to an actual build machine that is using some CICD tool (github, gitlab, azure pipelines or plain old jenkins etc).

Comment: The file image will contain files from multiple repos.

Comment: it doesn't matter. You do `git clone onerepo.git; git clone otherrepo.git;` and then in your Dockerfile you do `COPY onerepo somedirinimage` next line `COPY otherrepo someotherdirinimage`. and then call `docker build` This script will be your build script, it could be a job/step in a CICD pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone yourrepo
```

you need to run an ssh agent and add your private ssh key in it by ssh-add command
then run docker build with --ssh default